# Linearization of an expression

Tags: kinematics, terminology, calculus, approximations, linearized-theory

I'm doing a physics lab and I have a question that asks me to linearize the expression of time (it gives me the equation for time) in function of the mass.

I don't want any solution, just want to know what linearization means in physics (I know its something graph related).

Comment: Do you mean you need to draw a graph of your data that is a straight line? If so we will need to know the equation relating mass and time. For example if it's a mass on a spring we'd expect something like $T = 2\pi\sqrt{m/k}$ and in that case you would get a straight line by plotting $m$ on the $x$ axis and $T^2$ on the $y$ axis.

Comment: It's exactly the equation I was talking about. Thank you, now it makes sense

Comment: @NeaguCristian, John Rennie gave you the linearization for one particular equation.  Would you like to see an explanation of the concepts that will allow you to linearize a fairly wide range of different equations?

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, that would be very useful, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linearization of functions generally follows a few very specific steps.  The solution already given by John Rennie will serve as an example.

The idea is to match a given equation to the standard equation of a straight line:
$$T=2\pi \sqrt {m/k}, \tag{1}$$
$$y=mx+b \tag{2}.$$

$y$ is the dependent variable in equation (2), which is the standard equation of a straight line, and I need to identify a dependent variable in equation (1).  I choose $T$ as my dependent variable.

$x$ is the independent variable in equation (2), and I need to identify an independent variable in equation (1).  Based on my choice of $T$ as the dependent variable, I choose $\sqrt m$ as my independent variable.

Note that $m$ in equation (2) is not the same $m$ that is contained in equation (1), and it is the constant associated with the independent variable in equation (2).  This implies that I want to group all constants together in equation (1) and associate those constants with the $m$ in equation (2).  A bit of algebra yields $\frac {2 \pi}{\sqrt k}$ as the constants that I am looking for.

Thus, equation (1) may be slightly modified to be
$$T = \frac {2 \pi}{\sqrt k} \sqrt m. \tag{3}$$

Comparing equation (2) with equation (3) yields a one-to-one correspondence between the two equations for the dependent variable, the constant, and the independent variable.  This means that if $T$ is plotted on the vertical (dependent) axis and $\sqrt m$ is plotted on the horizontal (independent) axis, a straight line will result with a slope of $\frac {2 \pi}{\sqrt k}$ and a y-intercept ("b" in equation (2)) of 0.

Obviously, this is not the exact equation that John Rennie recommended.  Mathematically, it is not as "neat" to deal with square roots, so a bit of algebraic manipulation of the original equation yields the following:
$$T^2 = 4 \pi^2 \frac{m}{k}. \tag{4}$$

A bit of algebraic manipulation can be used to group all of the constants together, yielding:
$$T^2 = \frac {4 \pi^2}{k} m. \tag{5}$$

Following the procedure outlined above, it is seen that $T^2$ is the dependent variable, $\frac {4 \pi^2}{k}$ is the constant, $m$ is the independent variable, and 0 is the y-intercept.  Thus, if $T^2$ is plotted against $m$, a straight line results with a slope of $\frac {4 \pi^2}{k}$ and a y-intercept of 0, which is the recommended solution from John Rennie.

Comment: @ZadeJohnson, thanks for the edit.  I don't use Latex frequently enough to gain much expertise, and your edit really helped.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can also try to expand a non-linear function in Taylor series about some point, because technically this is what is called [linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearization). Taylor expansion is good at this, because usually first term (or even couple of terms) of expansion is linear one(s). For example, if you have equation

$$T = \frac {2 \pi}{\sqrt k} \sqrt m. \tag{1}$$

and you know that mass $m$ is very small, close to zero, i.e. equation defines oscillation of a particle for example. So you in this case could expand $\sqrt m$ function about a point $m=0$. The only problem here is that this function has singularity because one of the function derivatives is undefined at $0$. So you have to expand a little bit corrected equation, which avoids singularity, namely $\sqrt {m+a}$. Expanding that around $m=0$ in Taylor series gives :

$$ \sqrt{a} + \frac {m}{2 \sqrt{a}} - \frac {m^2}{8 a^{3/2}} + \frac {m^3}{16 a^{5/2}} - \frac {5 m^4}{128 a^{7/2}} + \frac {7 m^5}{256 a^{9/2}} + \ldots \tag 2$$

First term is a constant, and second term is linear, the rest ones - are non-linear corrections. Hence you can substitute first two terms into equation (1), which gives :

$$ T = \frac {2 \pi}{\sqrt k} \left( {\sqrt{a} + \frac {m}{2 \sqrt{a}}} \right) \tag{3} $$

So, we have arrived at linear $T(m)$ *approximation*. Keep in mind, that when your independent variable real data is more and more farther from expansion point,- the more $y(x)$ expanded function will give incorrect results, so you have to be careful thinking about what point(s) to expand Taylor series.